# Error with debian package installation

Tags: installation, vlc, debian

I have downloaded the deb package for vlc media player to install it in offline mode.

But when i try to install by double clicking on it, I'm getting the following error:

```
dependacy is not satisfiable:vlc-nox
```

I'm using ubuntu-13.04-desktop-amd64.

I can't try `apt-get` method as I don't have an Internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

you can install it from source,

visit http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-sources.html

Comment: Rather than just providing a link(which could easily go dead), it would be more helpful if you could provide some detail on *how* to install the app from source.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Let me try to install with tar. :)